# resource-oriented form_for breaks in rails 4.1 and/or ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I installed ruby 2.1.5 and rails 4.1.8 and 
    <%= form_for(@admin) do |f| %> 
comes up with ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

I then installed in-between versions (ruby 2.0.0 with rails 4.0.6 works fine):

- ruby 2.0.0-p481 with rails 4.0.6 - no problem
- ruby 2.0.0-p481 with rails 4.0.12 - no problem
- ruby 2.0.0-p481 with rails 4.1.8 - ArgumentError
- ruby 2.1.5 with rails 4.0.12 - ArgumentError
- ruby 2.1.5 with rails 4.1.8 - ArgumentError

I compared the gems between the ruby 2.0.0 rails 4.0.12 and ruby 2.1.5 rails 4.0.12 versions: 
only differences:

1. bundler 1.7.6 versus 1.6.2
2. psych 2.0.5 versus 2.0.0
3. test-unit 2.1.5.0 versus 2.0.0.0
4. and libv8 both 3.16.14.7 x86_64-darwin, but darwin-14 in ruby 2.1.5
   and darwin-13 in 2.0.0

Other than that everything is exactly the same, they are brand new rails apps with nothing in place but an admin scaffold

and: the form_for works fine, if I use 
    <%= form_for :admin, url: admins_path do |f| %> 
for the new action, and saves alright.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why things break is gem meta_search. Without it all is well. Replaced it with gem ransack.